# Python - iterate through the list value for newline

Tags: python-2.7

I am getting some large logs from a several sources and appending them to a list. All of the list values have several \n characters.

Once the list has been populated with the logs I require, I want to output them to a file in $HOME like so:

```
def logfile_creation(self):
  with open(os.path.join(self.homedir, self.logfile), 'w') as logoutput:
    for output in self.logs:
      logoutput.writelines(str(output))
```

When I read the logoutput file, instead of a newline the \n character is printed. I assume this is occurring because each list value is being converted into a string with str(), however this seems required for writelines to output into the file.

What's the best way to process the newline as it's outputted into the file, rather than printing \n?

Comment: What exactly is `output` before you turn it into a string?

Comment: output is the value in self.logs

Comment: Yes, well, that was not very insightful. I mean, is it a string, or a list, or some other object, and how does it typically look like?

Comment: It's a string, and the output looks like this: http://pastebin.com/rxAeaTbJ

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone was wondering, the way I resolved this was to use:

logoutput.writelines(str(output).replace('\n', '\n'))

Easy as that :)